# deleting one square from a row in sqlite DataBase

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database table with 2 columns NAME and AGE 
and three rows . 
how can I delete only one name from the NAME column ?
I don't want to delete the whole row

Comment: post what your code

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

To control what to delete you use the `WHERE` clause

[image]

check the [docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_delete.html)

Answer (score 0):

The DELETE statement removes entire rows from the table.

To modify some value(s) in some rows(s), use the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Name = NULL          -- or empty string, or whatever the new value should be
WHERE Name = 'OldName';
```